# Interaction Succubus + Avleda rune

Tags: werewolv.es

In 'Order of Night actions' Succubus redirects are listed before item effects. What does this mean for a combination of a Succubus redirect and an Avleda rune?

Example: Succubus redirects avatar A to avatar B, but avatar C has used avleda rune on avatar B.

Based on the order of night actions I would expect: avatar A is redirected to B during processing redirects, and then avatar A is redirected from B to C during 'item effects'. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently tested with the following setup

A Succubus,
B Villager,
C Lycan,
D Seer

Seer tried to check Succubus, Succubus redirected Seer to the villager, while the Lycan used the avleda rune on the villager.

The Seer got "C is a member of the wolfpack"

So it's working as expected with the right order.

Credit to: Niji, Rox, Diamond Dove